# Multiple triggers don't work on firebird

Tags: database, events, triggers, firebird

```
create trigger tr_buFile_fileid for BUFiles before insert as 
begin
IF (NEW.FileID IS NULL) THEN NEW.FileID = GEN_ID(FileID_generator, 1);
end
create trigger tr_buFile_insert for BUFiles after insert as 
begin 
update miscitems set TotalSize = TotalSize + new.BuFileSize;
end

create trigger tr_buFile_update for BUFiles after update as 
begin 
if (new.DeletionTime < '9223372036854775807' and new.DeletionTime != old.DeletionTime) then
update miscitems set TotalSize = TotalSize - old.BuFileSize;
end
```

I created three triggers on a firebird database. My application use odbc connection to operate on the database. The problem is that the second trigger (tr_buFile_insert) doesn't work if make an insertion on the BuFiles table. However this trigger works if I test them in SQL Manager for InterBase/Firebird.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Shiping

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How do you know that your trigger doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your triggers seems ok . 
I am afraid you are connecting to another db from application . Please check it . 
Please also check the trigger status  is **"ACTIVE"**